# Workout difference in months in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, date

I would like to work out the difference in months

at the moment I have this code:

```
dateInterval = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
```

But that returns a value in seconds, I would like to see the difference between the dates in months.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *startDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:@"07/03/2011"];
NSDate *endDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:@"07/06/2011"];
NSInteger month_delta = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0] month];
NSLog(@"---------------------------->>%d", month_delta);
[inputFormatter release]; // <-- in case not using ARC
```

it will log:

---------------------------->>3

Comment: +1 this is the right way to do it.  It will even work for > 12 month differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a NSDateComponents from the NSDates in question and just subtract the total months. (Total months = 12*year+currentMonth)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateComponents

Comment: What if there aren't 12 months in a year?  What if you're using a different calendar? Some calendars have leap months.